# Springboot Custom JSON Deserializer/Serializer are not working on Docker - Jenkins (O) / Gitlab CI/CD (X)

Tags: json, docker, jenkins, gitlab, objectmapper

I'm having some trouble with custom JSON Serialize/Deserialize issue.

In our project, we use **springBootVersion = '2.3.1.RELEASE'** and I added dependencies like below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

As I searched on websites, if i add **'spring-boot-starter-web'** on springboot version 2.x.x, it seems like the project can use **jackson library** that controls JSON forms.

---

For client-server commuication, we use JSON form and the brief process is same as the picture below.

[communication process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVi4C.jpg)

For release event, process is like this.

1. pull from git branch
2. gradle bulid with gradle wrapper
3. based on .jar file, make Docker image with Docker file
4. docker-compose.yml up with new docker image

However, when I make docker image-docker container on Gitlab CI/CD, JSON serialize/deserialize are not working with error messages.

`Excepion--------org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type "java.time.LocalDate" from String "20210412": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '20210412' could not be parsed at index 0; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type "java.time.LocalDate" from String "20210412": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '20210412' could not be parsed at index 0`

Regarding this error message, it seems like that there is someting wrong with JSON controlling on server side.

**The weird part of this problem is that Jenkins and GitLab CI/CD are making different result with same file on same server.**

On Jenkins and GitLab CI/CD, all files are same besides the file directory and file owner.Jenkins directories are possessed by root:root, but based on GitLab CI/CD property, all files that related to GitLab CI/CD are possessed by gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner.

For building and release process, Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml are totally same and docker releasing process are successfully done in both CI/CD sites.

What makes the JSON serialize/deserialize on GitLab CICD not working..?! Please help....!!

Comment: no, I send String from client like this {input: {rcToDt: "20210412"}}

Comment: Well, we intentionally made custom JSON serializer/deserializer to use date format like "yyyymmdd". Thanks for your kind comments but this is not a fundamental solution....:(